# Dart: How to pass function as parameter

Tags: flutter, dart

Id like to call a function from another function, this is my code:

```
  void fooA () {
    //do something
  }
  
  void fooB (fooC) {
    fooC();
  }
  
  fooB (fooA);
```

Why is fooA not executed?

Comment: its working fine what's error are you facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you provided functions:

```dart
void fooA () {
  print('hi');
}

void fooB (fooC) {
  fooC();
}

main() {
  fooB (fooA);
}
```

Output:

```
hi
```

However, it is better to fully type function arguments, as in:

```dart
void fooA() {
  print('hi');
}

void fooB(void Function() fooC) {
  fooC();
}

main() {
  fooB(fooA);
}
```

Note the fully descriptive type declaration `void Function() fooC`. Doing so enables the compiler to use static type checking to ensure the passed in function has the correct parameter and return types.

References

- [PREFER using function type syntax for parameters.](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#prefer-using-function-type-syntax-for-parameters)
- [PREFER inline function types over typedefs.](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#prefer-inline-function-types-over-typedefs)
- [Dart language specification](https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.10.pdf), section 20.5, "20.5 Function Types."